# How does @type import('./$types') Comment Syntax work in SvelteKit?

Tags: typescript, sveltekit, jsdoc

I'm currently learning SvelteKit and came across some code that I don't get the syntax of.

In `+page.server.ts` I don't understand this syntax:

```js
/** @type {import('./$types').PageServerLoad} */
```

To my untrained eye this looks like it's just commented out but the `/** */` is doing something that ensures it works. No idea.

Comment: The first is indeed a comment - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html. The other's just an object - you'll need to know basic JS to use TS.

Comment: Hey David, welcome to StackOverflow! I did edit out the question about Prisma and suggest you to post about it in another question because it is unrelated to SvelteKit, rather node.js. Also, in your new question you could add a bit more surrounding code about Prisma to make it easier for others to understand what is going on.

Comment: Fair enough, I learned C++ in the early 2000's so the plethora of JS shorthand is still a learning experience for me. I appreciate the explanation of the $types alias - makes sense thank you!

Also, correct me if I am wrong but after looking into it a bit more deeply that's a JSDOC comment which is why it still has an effect on the rest of the code right?

Comment: I wasn't even aware that this is a non-JSDoc feature. So, I learned sth today, thanks. I added a bit more detail about type checking and autocompletion in my answer and a link to type declaration files. I hope that makes it more understandable. Also, I can recommend this blog post to understand different JS syntax variants: https://www.taniarascia.com/es6-syntax-and-feature-overview/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SvelteKit generates a `.svelte-kit` directory whenever you run a dev or build command. In this directory are many files that are generated for prerendering and also type definitions. These definitions give you autocompletion and error checking in text editors that support TypeScript.

`$types` is an alias to the respective `$types.d.ts` [type declaration file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/type-declarations.html) in the `.svelte-kit/types/src/routes/...` folder.

[image: Shows the files and folders in the .svelte-kit directory]

These types can be imported, so that your text editor can understand the types of your load function. The types can be imported in two ways:

#### A. JSDoc comment + TypeScript-specific import types

Let's say you have a `page.server.ts` file in the file path `src/routes/blog/[slug]`. This gives you autocompletion and type checking on the params object as seen below.

```js
/** @type {import('./$types').PageServerLoad} */
export const load = async ({ params }) => {
  params.slug // autocompletes, no error
  params.snail 
      // ^^^^^ error: Property 'snail' does not 
      //       exist on type 'RouteParams'
}
```

This looks like regular JSDoc comment but the `import()` function is TypeScript-specific. More about it in the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#import-types) (thanks to [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75914611/two-questions-about-some-sveltekit-related-syntax#comment133899839_75914611) for mentioning the link).

*JSDoc comments might be limited. It seems to support annotating [modules](https://jsdoc.app/tags-module.html).*

#### B. TypeScript type annotation

If you are using TypeScript you can also use another syntax:

```
import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types';

export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ params }) => {
  // ... 
}
```

---

**Further reading** (about how TypeScript integrates into text editors/IDEs):

- https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools
- https://github.com/typescript-language-server/typescript-language-server
- https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/